# Master-detail relationship between standard objects

Tags: sobject, master-detail, data-model

Is there any master detail relationship between standard objects? If not, then why there is no master detail relationship between them? I am unable to find such relation between them.

Answer (score 4):

There are indeed Master Detail relationship between Standard object. Opportunity and Opportunity product (Opportunity Line Item) are one example of this.

But you can't create a new MD between Standard objects. Salesforce doesn't gave any reason for this may be some internal handling because MD affect security, sharing and permission part.

But you can vote this Idea
[Allow Master Detail Relationships between Standard Objects](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HBN2) to enable it for standard  objects.

Comment: I don't think it's something we'll see. Standard objects have various CRM features built around them that don't lend themselves well to the structural changes caused by altering their nature. Moreover, managed packages rely on standard objects behaving in predictable ways. Detail objects on a M-D relationship have no Owner field, for example. If you forced a standard object to become a Detail object, then managed code that mentions that object's Owner field would fail to compile when you install the package.

Comment: But I don't see such relation between opportunity and opportunity product. It is lookup relationship with some exceptions.

Comment: @DilipIrabatti you can create rollup between Opportunity and opportunity line item. Lookup don't allow them.

Comment: @TusharSharma that's why I said it is lookup relationship with some exceptional cases. If you check opportunity product field, it's relation is a lookup with opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

A few seconds of searching

> You can define master-detail relationships between custom objects or between a custom object and a standard object. However, the standard object cannot be on the detail side of a relationship with a custom object. In addition, you cannot create a master-detail relationship in which the User or Lead objects are the master.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/relationships_among_objects.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know this things. I am excepting something else.

Comment: You may have to change your expectations to something more realistic like what the docs say. You can’t have a MD between standard and standard as the docs state a standard cannot be the detail in the MD relationship

Comment: I understand that we can't create master detail relationship between standard objects or master can't be on detail side. But salesforce could handle on there side. My concern is why they ain't created such a relation.

Comment: With that I have voted to close the question as only SF can answer that. Anything else is pure speculation and opinion

Comment: @Eric I agree with you.